# Return queried model in Eloquent attribute

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

I'm using Laravel's eloquent ORM, and I was hoping to be able to return a queried laravel model as an attribute, or more ideally as an eloquent relation. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
class CalendarEvent extends Model
{
    protected $appends = array('conflicts');

    public function getConflictsAttribute () {
        $conflicts =  CalendarEvent::where('calendar_event_type','=',$this->calendar_event_type)
                      ->where('start','<',$this->end)
                      ->where('end','>',$this->start)
                      ->get();   

        return $conflicts;
    }
}
```

This is an attempt to get over-lapping calendar events, which would be the conflicting events, returned as an object against each event.

This would then mean any query run would return the conflicts :

```
$event = CalendarEvent::where('id','=',123)->first()->toJson();
$event; // JSON object should contain conflicting events
```

This results in a non-laravel 500 error, and a blank page. The storage/logs/laravel is not appended to. My /var/log/site-error.log has this appended during the request:

> PHP message: PHP 324.
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->attributesToArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2454
>   PHP message: PHP 325.
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->mutateAttributeForArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2518
>   PHP message: PHP 326. Illuminate\Support\Collection->toArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2764
>   PHP message: PHP 327. array_map()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1103
>   PHP message: PHP 328.
>   Illuminate\Support\Collection->Illuminate\Support{closure}()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1103
>   PHP message: PHP 329. Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->toArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1102
>   PHP message: PHP 330.
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->attributesToArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2454
>   PHP message: PHP 331.
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->mutateAttributeForArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2518
>   PHP message: PHP 332. Illuminate\Support\Collection->toArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2764
>   PHP message: PHP 333. array_map() /home/vagrant/silverback/ 2016/12/04
>   14:21:16 [error] 792#0: *42880 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1103
>   PHP message: PHP 370.
>   Illuminate\Support\Collection->Illuminate\Support{closure}()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1103
>   PHP message: PHP 371. Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->toArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1102
>   PHP message: PHP 372.
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->attributesToArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2454
>   PHP message: PHP 373.
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->mutateAttributeForArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2518
>   PHP message: PHP 374. Illuminate\Support\Collection->toArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2764
>   PHP message: PHP 375. array_map()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1103
>   PHP message: PHP 376.
>   Illuminate\Support\Collection->Illuminate\Support{closure}()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1103
>   PHP message: PHP 377. Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->toArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1102
>   PHP message: PHP 378.
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->attributesToArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2454
>   PHP message: PHP 379.
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->mutateAttributeForArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2518
>   PHP message: PHP 380. Illuminate\Support\Collection->toArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/larav 2016/12/04 14:21:16
>   [error] 792#0: *42880 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "ck/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2764
>   PHP message: PHP 417. array_map()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1103
>   PHP message: PHP 418.
>   Illuminate\Support\Collection->Illuminate\Support{closure}()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1103
>   PHP message: PHP 419. Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->toArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1102
>   PHP message: PHP 420.
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->attributesToArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2454
>   PHP message: PHP 421.
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->mutateAttributeForArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2518
>   PHP message: PHP 422. Illuminate\Support\Collection->toArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2764
>   PHP message: PHP 423. array_map()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1103
>   PHP message: PHP 424.
>   Illuminate\Support\Collection->Illuminate\Support{closure}()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1103
>   PHP message: PHP 425. Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->toArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1102
>   PHP message: PHP 426.
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->attributesToArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2454
>   PHP message: PHP 427.
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->mutateAttributeForArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Mode
>   2016/12/04 14:21:16 [error] 792#0: *42880 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "e/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2518 PHP message: PHP 464.
>   Illuminate\Support\Collection->toArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2764
>   PHP message: PHP 465. array_map()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1103
>   PHP message: PHP 466.
>   Illuminate\Support\Collection->Illuminate\Support{closure}()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1103
>   PHP message: PHP 467. Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->toArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1102
>   PHP message: PHP 468.
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->attributesToArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2454
>   PHP message: PHP 469.
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->mutateAttributeForArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2518
>   PHP message: PHP 470. Illuminate\Support\Collection->toArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2764
>   PHP message: PHP 471. array_map()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1103
>   PHP message: PHP 472.
>   Illuminate\Support\Collection->Illuminate\Support{closure}()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1103
>   PHP message: PHP 473. Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->toArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php:1102
>   PHP message: PHP 474.
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->attributesToArray()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2454
>   PHP message: PHP 475. Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->mu
>   2016/12/04 14:21:16 [error] 792#0: *42880 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>   "ry\Grammars\MySqlGrammar->wrapValue()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Grammar.php:79
>   PHP message: PHP 511.
>   Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\MySqlGrammar->isJsonSelector()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php:225
>   PHP message: PHP 512. Illuminate\Support\Str::contains()
>   /home/vagrant/silverback/httpdocs/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/MySqlGrammar.php:255"
>   while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.42.1,
>   server: silverback.dev, request: "GET /test HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "silverback.dev"

**UPDATE:**
I've decided this just isn't possible using Eloquent ORM. What I'm essentially trying to do is a Mysql like this, attaching as a relationship:

```
select * from calendar_events as calendar_events_2 where calendar_events_2.start < calendar_events_1.end AND calendar_events_2.end > calendar_events_1.start
```

Instead I've relunctently opted for a foreach loop to attach the data after it has been fetched. I believe this is my only option.

```
foreach ($shoot_timeline_data as $shoot) {
    foreach ($shoot->booking_cases as $booking_case) {
        $booking_case->booking->conflicts = CalendarEvent::find_clashes(
            $booking_case->booking->calendar_event_type, 
            $booking_case->booking->start, 
            $booking_case->booking->end,
            [$booking_case->booking->id] // excludes this ID via 'whereNotIn'
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the error message? Your code seems to be fine. It may be due to missing characters possibly due to format change or something that results in `Carbon` error and the second or third `where` clause produces error. Nothing can be clear till exact error message can be read.

Comment: I've added some more information about errors, and changed my code example to show what I'm trying ton achieve with eager loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be arising out of appended attribute, where you are trying to get other model instances in an array. A different approach could be to define a relation on self like

```
class CalendarEvent extends Model{
    public function conflicts()
    { 
        return  $this->hasMany(CalendarEvent::class)
                ->where('calender_event_type','=', $this->calendar_event_type);
    }
}
```

Then you can try to query as

```
$event = CalendarEvent::where('id','=',123)->with('conflicts')->first()->toJson();
```

Haven't tested, but try to see if it works.

**EDIT**

Try using parameters with lazy loading

```
$event = CalendarEvent::where('id', '=', 123)->first();
or
$event = CalendarEvent::findOrFail(123);  //it will find the record by given primary key - 123 or fail i.e. throw 'MODELNOTFOUNDEXCEPTION'

$start = $event->start;
$end = $event->end;
$event->load('conflicts', function($query) use ($start, $end){
          $query->where('start', '<', $start)
                ->where('end', '>', $end)
        })->get();
```

Comment: This seems to be the way forward, I have to run this as a "lazy eager load" as otherwise the model's $this->start is null. However, even with a lazy eager load, sometime the $this->start and $this->end are returned as null. None of these database fields are null.

  $shoot_timeline_data->load([
   'booking_cases.booking.conflicts',
  ]);

Comment: In that case you can load the relationship after the model has been fetched. `$event=CalendarEvent::where ('id','=',123)->first();` and then `$event->load ('conflicts');

Comment: That makes sense to me, but when I do that as an eloquent relationship like:             return $this->hasMany('App\CalendarEvent','calendar_event_type','calendar_event_type')
                          ->where('start','<',$this->end)
                          ->where('end','>',$this->start)
            ; , I receive an error: Illegal operator and value combination: at Builder->where('start', '<', null)

Comment: However, the database values are not null.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return it

```
class CalendarEvent extends Model
{
    protected $appends = array('conflicts');

    public function getConflictsAttribute () 
    {
        return CalendarEvent::where('calendar_event_type','=',$this->calendar_event_type)
                      ->where('start','<',$this->end)
                      ->where('end','>',$this->start)
                      ->get();   
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry my real code was much more complicated and I've simplified it, missing that line in my question. I have just tried this and I get a code 500 error, but not of a laravel kind.

Comment: "not of a laravel kind" means nothing showing in logs? `storage/logs/laravel.log`