# get user's name from another table view by user's id

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

Trying to set up ticket system in Laravel app but at the end stucked with

> How to show the user's name in the table view of `{{url/admin/support}}`, where trying to show the lists of opened tickets and users name who opened the tickets

```
$user = User::where('name')->first();
```

this is what I tried in controller and `<td>{{$user}}</td>` in view table.

This is `app/User`

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'funds',
        'role',
        'status',
        'skype_id',
        'enabled_payment_methods',
        'api_token',
        'last_login',
    ];

    .
    .
    .
```

help me..

Comment: `User::where('name', $name)->first()`?

Comment: undefined variable "name" ...

Comment: Better get user's info using him id. $user = User::find($user->id); Find method retrieve a model by its primary key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return queried model in Eloquent attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959230/return-queried-model-in-eloquent-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel you can get data from model simply by trying to access to attribute

```
$name = "admin";
$user = User::where("name", $name)->first();
echo $user->name; // returns "admin"
```

If you want to show user's name in view use following code:

```
<td>{{$user->name}}</td>
```

I think that you did not open documentation or examples at all.

Comment: well, in my tickets table <td>{{$ticket->id}} </td>
                              <td>{{$ticket->created_at}} </td>
                              <td>{{$ticket->user_id}} </td>
                              <td>{{$ticket->subject}} </td>
                              <td>{{$ticket->description}} </td>
                              <td>{{$unreadMessages}}</td>
                              <td>{{$ticket->status}} </td>      .... these are the things inserted but insttead of the user_id i want to show the name of user in views

Comment: You should check documentation and read about [relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)